# JSON Filter Lookup on SharePoint

Tags: json, sharepoint, filter

I've problem with JSON script.

Which is I have 2 List on SharePoint : first list (marketing catalog) using JSON Script for status column and second list (catalog order)
I've joined it with lookup column on second list (catalog order), but it show all status (active and non active), rather than i need only active is "show"

Thanks

for more detail I attached my screen shoot
[JSON Script to filter status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl8CW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Sharepoint on-premise 2019 (modern). Based on my information the possible way to achieve it is:

1. You cannot "expand" your lookup column for Choice field (I assume that Status column in Marketing Catalog is Choice field).
2. Add calculated column (for example StatusHidden) for Marketing catalog only to "copy" Status column as text field.
3. In Catalog order list show additional field for Calculated column - StatusHidden
4. In view for Catalog Order, filter items based on StatusHidden column equal to Active.

Comment: Hi, I'm using single text but on single text I'm using JSON script to make status active / non active (based on Today Date). So column can lookup.

Comment: Hi, so you can in Ctalog order list -> edit Calculated column - show additional fields - check Status. After that you can edit default view to filter only Status === Active.

Comment: Yap, Thanks . But I'm using single text how to show additional fields?

Comment: Hi, sorry are you using lookup column in catalog order? If so, you can show for this lookup column additional fields (Status column). Just go to lookup column settings, and there is addtional fields. Do you see Status column there?